# model theory - completeness of a theory

Tags: logic, model-theory

> For an $L$-structure $\mathcal{A}$, the $L$-theory of $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of $L$-sentences:
>   $$
> \mathrm{Th}_L(\mathcal A) = \{\sigma : \mathcal A \models \sigma\}
> $$
>
> Prove that $\mathrm{Th}_L(\mathcal A)$ is complete.

Whys is this true? Why can't there be an $L$-sentence such that it is neither true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume there's an $L$-sentence $\sigma$ that's neither true nor false. Then we have that $\mathcal{A}\nvDash\sigma$ and $\mathcal{A}\nvDash\neg\sigma$. But this is a contradiction since $\mathcal{A}\vDash\sigma$ if and only if $\mathcal{A}\nvDash\neg\sigma$, and vice versa, by definition of what a structure is.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a really basic question but why is it that you can construct such sentence that is neither true nor false under Godel's incompleteness theorem but not here? Thanks!

Comment: For a detailed explanation, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14710/300881). But basically, Godel's incompleteness theorem is not a negation of Godel's completeness theorem. Also, here we are dealing with a structure, not a set of sentences (which is what Godel's incompleteness theorem talks about).

Comment: @bof That's an incorrect statement of Godel's incompleteness theorem. There is a distinction between *truth in a model/structure* (fixing a structure $M$, everything is either true in $M$ or false in $M$) and *provability from a theory* (= truth in *every model* of that theory; since a given theory might have many disagreeing models, there are in general independent sentences, and this is what Godel's incompleteness theorem is about).

Comment: @bof For any sentence $\varphi$ and any structure $A$ the *definition* of $A\models \lnot \varphi$ is that $A\not\models \varphi$. It immediately follows that either $A\models \varphi$ or $A\models \lnot \varphi$.

Comment: thank you everyone